# EF Core removes the space between day and Hour in the SQL insert statement

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm using EF Core in a Blazor Server app using .NET8, and I have a weird issue when trying to insert some related entities into the database, regarding a Created (DateTime) column into the SQL.

I have the following base class :

```cs
public abstract class BaseAuditableEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    public virtual string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    public virtual string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And these are my domain classes: I have an `Address` class that inherits from the `BaseAuditableEntity` class. Of course, inside the `Address` class I have everything you can imagine related to an `Address`.

```cs
public class Property: BaseAuditableEntity
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public AddressId int { get; set; }
    public Land? Land { get; set; }
    public int? LandId { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Land: BaseAuditableEntity
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public AddressId int { get; set; }
}
```

In my UI Logic, I have a specific page where I create a `Land`. Everything works fine there (the `Land` is created, and also the associated new `Address` with it).

The problem is on my Properties page. Something is weird. I cannot create a `Property`, because the `Address` insertion is failing. And that is caused by a missing space between the DAY and HOUR on the SQL Statement.

Here is how my SQL Profiler looks :

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Addresses] ([AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [AddressLine3], [AddressLine4], [Apartment], [Building], [City], [Country], [County], [Created], [CreatedBy], [District], [Entrance], [Floor], [LastModified], [LastModifiedBy], [State], [Street], [StreetNumber], [TenantId], [ZipCode])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20);
',N'@p0 nvarchar(500),@p1 nvarchar(100),@p2 nvarchar(100),@p3 nvarchar(100),@p4 nvarchar(50),@p5 nvarchar(50),@p6 nvarchar(50),@p7 nvarchar(100),@p8 nvarchar(100),@p9 datetime2(7),@p10 nvarchar(4000),@p11 nvarchar(100),@p12 nvarchar(50),@p13 nvarchar(50),@p14 datetime2(7),@p15 nvarchar(4000),@p16 nvarchar(50),@p17 nvarchar(100),@p18 nvarchar(50),@p19 nvarchar(450),@p20 nvarchar(50)',@p0=NULL,@p1=NULL,@p2=NULL,@p3=NULL,@p4=NULL,@p5=NULL,@p6=NULL,@p7=NULL,@p8=NULL,@p9='2023-12-1408:42:32',@p10=N'cee1e3da-7ac3-45d4-a663-4cf266a23690',@p11=NULL,@p12=NULL,@p13=NULL,@p14=NULL,@p15=NULL,@p16=NULL,@p17=NULL,@p18=NULL,@p19=N'1127d001-97f1-4b5a-80ea-42f3eca4263d',@p20=NULL
```

Which generates this error :

> Error converting data type varchar to datetime2.

The problem is P9, which is the Created date.The format is '2023-12-1408:42:32'.

The only thing that is between my UI and Database logic, is an EF Core custom Interceptor that does something like this :

```cs
private void UpdateEntities(DbContext context)
{
     var userId = _currentUserService.UserId;
     var tenantId = _tenantProvider.TenantId;

     foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseAuditableEntity>())
     {
         switch (entry.State)
         {
             case EntityState.Added:
                 entry.Entity.CreatedBy = userId;
                 entry.Entity.Created = _dateTime.Now;
...
```

Where the `DateTimeService` (_dateTime) looks like this:

```cs
public class DateTimeService : IDateTime
{
    public DateTime Now
    {
        get
        {
            var createdDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var formattedDate = createdDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return DateTime.Parse(formattedDate);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to remove the usage of the DateTime service, and modified the Interceptor to have just :

```cs
entry.Entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
```

And, of course, in debugging the Created property date looks ok before inserting into the DB (the format).

Any idea why does the SQL generated by EF Core for this specific scenario forget to add the space between the DAY and HOUR ?

Comment: Why does your timeservice 1. create a DateTime object, then 2. format it to string just to 3. Parse that string again into a DateTime object? (Which is probably not the problem here, but anyway...)

Comment: Wanted to be verbose. Actually, my initial DateTimeService just returned DateTime.UtcNow.
I tried to manually parse it to see if that's the problem, so what you see here it was just a modified version of the DateTimeService.

Comment: The error complains that you tried to store a string in a date field, not about spaces. Dates have no format, they're binary values. ADO.NET, which EF uses, doesn't convert parameters to strings. It's quite possible the error is thrown by something else, like the interceptor, not the actual EF operation. Post the actual full exception text. The call stack or any inner exceptions could point to the actual method that caused the problem

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos -  it is strange the generated SQL statement that was post, because in it the date was set in this format  @p9='2023-12-1408:42:32'

Comment: ADO.NET wouldn't do that. Which means something else did. If it did, every developer would know about it - thousands if not millions of applications * millions of operations per day, means EF applications would throw such errors all the time

Comment: At the very least this is a case of `extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence`. We need a complete example that reproduces the problem, including the EF, database and driver versions.

Comment: More to the point. I don't understand what OP means by "space" in a DateTime. Any reasonable implementation of EFC provider would be using a parameter, which would use a binary representation of `DateTime`. If you are sending a `string` then you must be using `.UseConverter` (in your mapping) to instruct EFC to use string, and also supply a method to convert `DateTime` to `string`.

Comment: usually all timestamps like created/modified are implemented in the DB not in the client. for audit purposes (and if you have server side authentication, the usernames too). to reduce risk of tampering

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems the DateTime format was not actually the error... lol.
I thought that was the error, because I was just looking into the SQL Server profiler and saw that there it stopped...

Then, I just copy-pasted from the Profiler into the SQL Management Studio query... and... guess what? The profiler removes the space between the DAY and HOUR!!! The issue was elsewere, and it had nothing to do with everything I wrote here!

Sorry everyone for consuming your time, but maybe this will raise awareness of the fact that the MSSQL Server Profiler is bugged!

Comment: SQL Server Profiler is *deprecated* since 2014. The correct way to profile in the last decade is [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). I suspect the truncation only occurred in the grid that displayed the event you captured too.